# Помогите запустить пример: Reddit AP

Tags: reactjs

помогите запустить пример: https://rajdee.gitbooks.io/redux-in-russian/content/docs/advanced/ExampleRedditAPI.html

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "reduxapp",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "lite-server"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "lite-server": "^2.2.2",
    "babel-core": "^6.21.0",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.10",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.5.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.5.0",
    "webpack": "^1.14.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.23.0",
    "body-parser": "~1.17.1",
    "cookie-parser": "~1.4.3",
    "debug": "~2.6.3",
    "es6-promise": "^4.1.0",
    "express": "~4.15.2",
    "immutable": "^3.7.6",
    "isomorphic-fetch": "^2.2.1",
    "morgan": "~1.8.1",
    "pug": "~2.0.0-beta11",
    "react": "^0.14.7",
    "react-dom": "^0.14.7",
    "react-redux": "^4.4.8",
    "redux": "^3.6.0",
    "redux-logger": "^3.0.1",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.2.0",
    "serve-favicon": "~2.4.2"
  }
}
```

сборка проходит без ошибок

но при открытии в браузере index.html

```
    ...
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script src="/js/index.js"></script>
    ...
```

получаю ошибку:

```js
Uncaught TypeError: middleware is not a function
    at http://localhost:3000/js/index.js:30247:17
    at Array.map (native)
    at http://localhost:3000/js/index.js:30246:28
    at createStore (http://localhost:3000/js/index.js:29389:34)
    at configureStore (http://localhost:3000/js/index.js:30445:34)
    at Object.exports.__esModule (http://localhost:3000/js/index.js:27787:43)
    at __webpack_require__ (http://localhost:3000/js/index.js:20:30)
    at Object.<anonymous> (http://localhost:3000/js/index.js:57:14)
    at __webpack_require__ (http://localhost:3000/js/index.js:20:30)
    at http://localhost:3000/js/index.js:40:18
(anonymous) @ applyMiddleware.js:49
(anonymous) @ applyMiddleware.js:48
createStore @ createStore.js:65
configureStore @ configureStore.jsx:9
exports.__esModule @ Root.jsx:6
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap 6ee7905…:19
(anonymous) @ index.jsx:5
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap 6ee7905…:19
(anonymous) @ bootstrap 6ee7905…:39
(anonymous) @ bootstrap 6ee7905…:39
```

и не могу понять как ее исправить

Спасибо

Answer (score 0):

проблема оказалась в изменении интерфейса `redux-logger`

в файле `configureStore.js` надо изменить импорт модуля

с:

```
import createLogger from 'redux-logger'
```

на:

```
import { createLogger } from 'redux-logger'
```